# How can I consolidate each thread result - java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I want execute some java logic with multiple threads and that method return a List. So finally I want all threads result into single List? Is it possible with Java ExecutorService or Multithreading ? or any other java frameworks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do it, here is my suggestion:

Create a list of `Callable` (see more about it in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)):

```
List<Callable<Object>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add your tasks to this list:

```
callables.add(() -> {
            // do something
        });
```

Then invoke those Callables by passing them to the `invokeAll()` method of `ExecutorService` and receive a List of `Future<Object>`. For example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<Future<Object>> results = executor.invokeAll(callables);
```

You can then get each of the thread results by getting them via index call from the `result` list - in the same order as which you passed them to your Callable list.

So, to get the result of the first thread that you passed to the Callable list, simply do:

```
  CastedResult result = (CastedResult) results.get(0).get();
```

Finally, you can collect all results in a single list as you wish.

Also, this is a helpful [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial) on how to use `ExecutorService` (and remember to shutdown the Executor after you finish working with it, as explained here).

Answer (score 0):

> I want execute some java logic with multiple threads and that method return a List. So finally I want all threads result into single List?

There are a couple of ways that I can think of to do this.  One way would be to pass a `BlockingQueue` into all of the jobs.  Then they each can be adding results into the same collection.

Any other solution probably means that each job returns a `List` and as you join with the jobs you add the per-job list into a final list.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
List<Future<List<Foo>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JOBS; i++) {
    // add another job to the thread-pool and record the future
    futures.add(threadPool.submit(new Callable<List<Foo>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Foo> call() throws Exception {
            // create the list here
            return list;
        }
    });
}
// shutdown the pool but the jobs continue running
threadPool.shutdown();
List<Foo> finalList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
for (Future<List<Foo>> future : futures) {
    // calling get waits for each job to finish in order
    // we add all of the results from the job list into the final list
    finalList.addAll(future.get());
}
```

This waits for each of the jobs in order.  If you want to add the results into the list as they finish then you can use a [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).